# Print elements of a tuple from most inner element

Tags: python, python-3.x, tuples

I'm with a python problem, I'm new on this and wanting to know what I'm missing.

The thing I want to do is to print a nested tuple, but from inside to outside.

As an example: `('C', ('B', ('A', ())))` should be printed as `null, A, B, C`

All tuples maximum size is 2.

I was thinking on using a recursive function in order to do that; I have this code, but I don't know what's wrong.

```
def tuplePrint(t):
    if len(t) > 1:
        return(tuplePrint(t[1])
    else:
        return t[0]

x = ('E', ('B', ('A', ())))
print(tuplePrint(x))
```

I'm not asking for the answer for the problem (that would be great), but if only you could tell me what's wrong with the code I'd be grateful.

Anyone? any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: To start with, you only have a single print statement, and it's outside of any loops.  So it's never going to print more than a single value.  Also, `t[0]` for an empty tuple will raise an `IndexError` exception (because you're trying to access an element that doesn't exist).

Comment: What you are asking for is effectively a [post-order traversal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal#Post-order) of an unbalanced binary tree.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The `return` statement on line 3 should not have a `(` before the contents of the `return`.
2. The base case of your recursion (the else statement, i.e. `len(t) <= 1`), should return the string `"null"` or a single-element list `["null"]`.
3. The recursive component of your function (`return tuplePrint(t[1])`) has to also incorporate the current element, so you probably want either `tuplePrint(t[1]) + [t[0]]` or `tuplePrint(t[1]) + " " + t[0]`.
4. Once your function returns a string like `"null A B E"` or a list like `[null, A, B, E]`, you want to print it comma-separated by joining the list: `", ".join(tuplePrint(x))` (in the string case, you should call `split()` on the string returned by `tuplePrint(x)`.

Resulting in:

```
def tuplePrint(t):
    if len(t) > 1:
        return tuplePrint(t[1]) + [t[0]]
    else:
        return ["null"]

x = ('E', ('B', ('A', ())))
print(", ".join(tuplePrint(x)))
# null, A, B, E
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Exactly what I wanted to know, and in an easy way.

Answer (score 1):

```
def tuple_print(t):
    x, xs = t
    v = 'null'
    if len(xs):
        v = tuple_print(xs)
    return ', '.join((v, x))
```

Answer (score 0):

this may work for you

```
def tuplePrint(t):
    if not t:
        answer.insert(0, "null")
    for each in t:
        if isinstance(each, tuple):
            tuplePrint(each)
        else:
            answer.insert(0, each)

x = ('E', ('B', ('A', ())))
answer = []
tuplePrint(x)
print(answer)
```